# Creation of a color coded strip-chart using Java FX 8 Charting

Tags: java, charts, javafx-8

I am trying to find a "reasonable" way of creating a color coded strip-chart based on Java FX 8 charting.

I don't have reputation points to post an image, but I am trying to create a much simpler version of something similar to the chart at the bottom of:

[Color coded strip chart](http://image.cimindustry.com/a/your-data-use-it-or-lose-it-0.jpg)

I.e. I'd like the bars to change color according to the current error state.  It would have about four states.
I have thought about trying some form of stacked bar chart but that seems like a bit of a kludge.  I had hoped to find a method using a gradient but haven't located a way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far to your question.

Comment: I would try something other than a chart.  IMO kludge is right.  It's not the 4 colors that's a problem, it's the number of time divisions in the stack of bars, each one means a new series.  These series would bear no relation to the data.

Comment: I haven't completed this yet, but what I am now planning to use is a StackPane.  I'm going to overlay rectangles of the appropriate size and color in each StackPane to create the composite stripchart.  This will probably be sufficient because I don't anticipate a *lot* of transitions in each chart.